# Decrease div width bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to decrease the black background width wise to make it more proportional to image and buttons.

This is the code for one of the component on page. Similar is the code for the other component as well.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-body" style="background-color: black;">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" class="Image" alt="Image">

        <div class="col text-center">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Login as a Coach</button>
          <br/>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Join as a Coach</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
```

[image: html page]

Expected Output:

[image: Output Webpage should look somewhat like this]

Comment: Whick Bootstrap version are you using? Version 3 (.panel) or version 4 (.card)

Comment: @bron bootstrap 4.6.0

Comment: Then use `.card` in your html, see https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/migration/#panels

Comment: FYI, if your buttons are actually for navigation, use anchor elements. The same style classes can be used to give them a button appearance.

Comment: Below the `template` for Bootstrap 4 using cards. I added some code to align it vertically on the page, except on mobile phones.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just want a more compact layout. You can do that with column configuration, as I've done here by reducing column size as screen size increases. I've also applied flexbox centering to the row with `justify-content-center`.

Note that I've eliminated the obsolete and unavailable panel classes and added a custom background class. I've also used Bootstrap's [border radius classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/borders/#border-radius) on the boxes and various [spacing classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/spacing/) for nicer fitment.

```css
.bg-black {
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center pt-2">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-lg-4">
      <div class="bg-black text-center p-3 mb-3 rounded-lg">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x400" class="img-fluid mb-2 rounded-lg" alt="">

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Log in as a Coach</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block mt-2">Join as a Coach</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-lg-4">
      <div class="bg-black text-center p-3 mb-3 rounded-lg">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x400" class="img-fluid mb-2 rounded-lg" alt="">

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Log in as a Coach</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mt-2 btn-block">Join as a Coach</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A "card" template for Bootstrap 4. Both cards are vertically aligned on the page. On mobile phone they are stacked.

Using `h-100 mh-100` on container-fluid will make full space from top to bottom. Vertical centering the cards is done with `align-content-sm-center` (sm meaning view width is min. 576px).

Click the 'Run code snippet' button and then click 'Full page' to see the difference between small and large browser view.

**Update** : removed some code that is not Bootstrap 4 related.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background-color: black;
}
.container-fluid {
  /* edit this for another max width */
  max-width: 1140px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid h-100 mh-100 d-flex align-content-sm-center">
    <div class="row align-content-sm-center pt-3">
        <div class="col-sm-6 pb-3">
            <div class="card border-0">
                <a href="#" class="card-img-top">
                    <img src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/new/standard/nature/111.webp" class="d-block img-fluid" alt="">
                </a>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Login as a Coach</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="#!" class="btn btn-primary">Login</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 pb-3">
            <div class="card border-0">
                <a href="#" class="card-img-top">
                    <img src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/new/standard/nature/120.webp" class="d-block img-fluid" alt="">
                </a>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Join as a Coach</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="#!" class="btn btn-primary">Join</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you explain why you used a href="#!"

Comment: The href="#" is a common way to show links in example code. In real live you have to update this and change the href="#" in a link of your site, for example href="login.html"

Comment: Updated the code to have only Bootstrap 4 classes.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-body" style="background-color: black;">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" class="Image" alt="Image">

        <div class="col text-center">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Login as a Coach</button>
          <br/>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Join as a Coach</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
```

```css
.panel-body {
    padding: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 10px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
button.btn.btn-primary {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 5px 0;
    background: #0c82af;
    border-color: #0c82af;
    padding: 6px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-body" style="background-color: black;">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" class="Image" alt="Image">

        <div class="col text-center">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Login as a Coach</button>
          <br/>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Join as a Coach</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).